# Overlapping issue in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

There is a purple box at left of "Havent got your code" section, how do i push it down so that it doesn't overlap?
Here is the link
http://responsivetest.net/#u=http://mattfursse.co.uk/sff/|640|1136|2

Here is the screenshot
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/399472/3800ff2b4e74bd1f6106b5c327fc38ab

Comment: adding fixed hright solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
h3.pretitle { overflow: visible; }
```

Or:

```
h3.pretitle { width: 100%; }
```

Both will do the job.

And maybe you have to clear the float, too with:

```
h3.pretitle { clear: both; }
```

Comment: adding fixed height solved the problem.. thanks for the heads up